# How to add exponent(superscript) symbol on a custom keyboard?

Tags: android, custom-keyboard, exponent

I am working on a custom keyboard but i'm stuck on adding exponent symbols, do i simply add "^"?? Here is my code, sorry im a noob

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:keyWidth="15%p"
        android:keyHeight="15%p" >
<Row>
            <Key android:codes="+"    android:keyLabel="a" android:horizontalGap="2%p"/>
            <Key android:codes="-"    android:keyLabel="b" android:horizontalGap="2%p"/>
            <Key android:codes="*"    android:keyLabel="c" android:horizontalGap="2%p" />
            <Key android:codes="/"    android:keyLabel="d" android:horizontalGap="2%p" />
            <Key android:codes="^"    android:keyLabel="^" android:horizontalGap="2%p" />
            <Key android:codes="("    android:keyLabel="(" android:horizontalGap="2%p"/>
            <Key android:codes=")"    android:keyLabel=")" android:horizontalGap="2%p"/>

        </Row>

        <Row>
            <Key android:codes="-1"    android:keyLabel="@drawable/backspace" android:keyWidth="34%p" android:horizontalGap="4%p"/>
            <Key android:codes="100"    android:keyLabel="Enter" android:keyWidth="53%p" android:horizontalGap="4%p"/>
        </Row>
    </Keyboard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```
 <Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"  
android:keyHeight="60dp">
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
    <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
    <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
    <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
    <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
    <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
    <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
    <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
    <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
    <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
    <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
    <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
    <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
    <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
    <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
    <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
    <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
    <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
    <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
    <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
    <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
    <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
    <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>       
    <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l"/>
    <Key android:codes="35,64" android:keyLabel="\# \@" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyLabel="CAPS" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="z"/>
    <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
    <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="c"/>
    <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="v"/>
    <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="b"/>
    <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="n"/>
    <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="m"/>
    <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."/>
    <Key android:codes="63,33,58" android:keyLabel="\? ! :" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>    
</Row>
<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel="," android:keyWidth="10%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>   
    <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
    <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>        
    <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="DEL" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
```